# How to digitally sign Images like JPG TIFF and BMP

Tags: digital-signature

I wish to digitally sign my image collection which consists of JPG , TIFF , BMP , SWf , Fla files.

My question is how to digitally sign these images? If I sign JPG or Tiff , whether signature will get attached to these files (as it happens in document files like PDF or MS word etc)? If so where it get store in file metadata fields , or remain outside? Can i extract signature data?
Please note I wish to sign these images Individually and do not want to get converted into any other format like PDF. Also I donot wish to sign it using email client.

Answer (score 2):

In general those formats were not designed with signing in mind, so your best option is to create a detached signature and keep it near the file. An alternative is to use wrapping signature but then other software won't be able to display the image until you remove the wrapper.

Storing the signature in metadata can be possible for some formats but what applications would be able to handle this?

Comment: @eEugene Mayevski 'EldoS : thanks for reply! Fine... but what if i want to sign Video files? Can I do it as there are many container formats like MKV , MXf etc? Does they contain any meta fields to store signature along with main content?Is there any such format?

Comment: @ssppune I am not an expert in file formats, but my general comments apply to video as well - you can put the signature into custom attributes (where they are available) but only your software will be able to make use of this signature. So detached signature is the most viable option, probably.

Comment: Signature in metadata would be ignored by software not designed for it, but a signature over the image content *would* facilitate repudiation of altered images.  Just point to the signature and demonstrate that it doesn't match the bits, to encourage reasonable doubt.

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been a long time, but you might want to look into steganography. Metadata can be extracted and removed from files. Steganography will allow you to embed digital signatures(encrypted phrases) in a way that is almost only detectable using statistical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a mime container which will contain the original image and a detached signature.

Attached signatures are only useful for specific apps, as they are not standard.

Answer (score -2):

Try answering the posters question folks, and not giving another unneeded and unwanted opinion, it's way to common these days in my humble opinion.
Obviously what the poster asked for is to use a signature to copyright his works, so you need to sign the image, period, And a method to do so.

So let's see... grab Gimp or Photoshop. Get your image and create a new layer with transparent background. write in a signature with your mouse or digital pen in an area near the bottom right edge. Choose merge layers and flatten image. Seems like that would do it.

Comment: The question asks for a "digital signature" (a hash of file bytes), not a pixel-based watermark. The other answers are giving related advice.